# Is it more efficient to use the keyword this when accessing instance variables?

Tags: c#, java, android, oop, instance-variables

The `this` keyword is optional when accessing instance fields, properties, and methods in languages like C# and Java.

I've been doing some best practice research on various languages lately, and have noticed many places recommend creating a local reference to instance fields within methods because it's more efficient. The latest mention was in an Android tutorial.

It seems to me that if you specify `this._obj`, it should be just as efficient as a local variable. Is this correct or is it just as 'costly' as not using `this`?

Does the answer change from the Android Dalvik VM, to standard Java, to C#?

```
public class test {
    private Object[] _obj;

    protected void myMethod() {
        Object[] obj = _obj;

        // Is there an appreciable differnce between
        for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
            // do stuff
        }

        // and this?
        for(int i = 0; i < this._obj.length; i++) { 
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to know if something is more efficient than something else a good first step is to *measure* it. Or, in the case of syntax-y issues, to read the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no change in efficiency.  Remember that in many languages, several equivalent expressions will reduce down to identical statements in the underlying bytecode or assembly or whatever the higher level language translates into.

The answer is uniform across the languages and VMs you mention.

Use it when necessary, like when a method parameter has the same name as an instance variable.

Unless CPU cycles (or memory, etc.) are a top priority, value clarity above less expressive but more efficient language syntax.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking that the use of `this` may narrow scope, but I see that doesn't matter much. So are they just being silly in creating a local Cursor reference here [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html) ?

Comment: @Josh: there are a number of reasons you might want to take a local reference. In a multi-threaded environment, for example, you can use that to prevent damage caused by another thread changing the instance field. According to their own comment, the Dalvik VM is much slower accessing fields. I think they should know what they're talking about. But in the end, *measurements* will always have the last say in this matter.

Comment: I understand that I can measure it, but I'm trying to get a handle on how things work so I can better understand results that I receive. Not to mention I don't have all of the different environments at my finger tips.

Answer (score 3):

For at least standard Java, there is a small, small difference.

I modified your example a little to this:

```
public class test {
    private Object[] _obj;

    protected void myMethodLocal() {
        Object[] obj = _obj;

        // Is there an appreciable differnce between
        for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
            // do stuff
        }
    }

   protected void myMethodMember() {
        // and this?
        for(int i = 0; i < this._obj.length; i++) { 
            // do stuff
        }
   }
}
```

So `myMethodLocal()` will cache `_obj` into a local variable, while `myMethodMember()` uses the class member `_obj`.

Now, let's decompile this (using **javap**):

```
protected void myMethodLocal();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #2; //Field _obj:[Ljava/lang/Object;
   4:   astore_1
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   istore_2
   7:   iload_2
   8:   aload_1
   9:   arraylength
   10:  if_icmpge   19
   13:  iinc    2, 1
   16:  goto    7
   19:  return

protected void myMethodMember();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   aload_0
   4:   getfield    #2; //Field _obj:[Ljava/lang/Object;
   7:   arraylength
   8:   if_icmpge   17
   11:  iinc    1, 1
   14:  goto    2
   17:  return
```

Without going into details, the latter example has to access the `_obj` field every loop iteration, while the first example already had it cached in a local reference and just needs to access the local reference.

What does this equate to in speed difference?

**Not much.**

While the difference between accessing a local reference and a class-reference means a lot more in a language like [Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables), for Java, you really don't need to worry. It's much more important to keep your code readable and maintainable than to fret over details like that.

(Plus, the above bytecode doesn't take into account what the JIT compiler might do, anyway).

If you get the instance field by a *function*, like `getObj()`, I would plug that into a variable, so you don't need to keep calling `getObj()` each time you want to use the same field.

---

Also, just as a minor note, you should probably call your class `Test` instead of `test.` Java tends to favor Upper Camel Case for class names.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword is used for readability and most importantly making variable names unambiguous. It has no affect on performance whatsoever.

Comment: I'd say it's the opposite. Putting `this` in front of variables (when not necessary) just clutters the code, making it less readable.

Comment: Yes, in some cases I would agree, in others I would disagree.

Answer (score 0):

On modern PC, this may not make any difference irrespective of languages due to caching - if memory location is cached on on-chip dye then it wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect using local variable is only a single reference (the value is on the stack), while using member variable is 2 reference (reference to **this**, which is on the stack, then reference to the variable itself, which is on the heap)

Depending on the system, either heap or stack access could be faster.

But like what [Jonathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203600/jonathon) said, unless speed is very important, don't bother yourself with this. It will only reduce readability for negligible performance.

Comment: I bet that a reference to this is on the stack almost all the time. I don't see how **adding** a local variable to the whole thing can **reduce** the number of references.

Comment: even though this is on the stack, the value of the member variable is on the heap. By assigning to a local variable, you copying that value from the heap to the stack.

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding how references work in Java. When you assign a reference to a variable you create a copy of the reference, not a copy of the value.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163344/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-the-keyword-this-when-accessing-instance-variables/5163461#5163461> exactly demonstrates my point. The reference of a local variable is a **copy**, which resides on the stack. The value of the variable is on the heap. When using **this**, the value of **this** is a **copy** on the stack. The reference of the member variable is on the heap, depending on the value of **this**. The value of the member variable is also on the heap. got tired of waiting for the 5-min interval before i can edit

Comment: I think I understand you now: you're saying that with a local variable you only need to follow one reference, but without it, you need to follow two references. Is that it? If so, your choice of words was not the best. In Java a "reference" is something like a smart pointer. The act of following a reference can be called "dereferencing". The wikipedia article for [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science%29) explains the difference.

Comment: yes, and my apologies for the wrong choice of words. I'm rather new and still learning. I really appreciate you pointing out my mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, no. Accessing "this._obj.Length" ends up generating code like:

```
mov eax, [ecx + offset_of_obj]
mov eax, [eax + offset_of_length]
```

where as "obj.length" ends up generating code like:

```
mov eax, [esp + offset_of_obj]
mov eax, [eax + offset_of_length]
```

In practice, maybe, but probably not. With virtually every x86 calling convention there are only 3 scratch registers "eax", "ecx", and "edx". All other registers must be saved on the stack before they can be updated. If you have a long function, and you don't need to access "this" then the ecx register could be repurposed to hold temporary variables, and could thus reduce the amount of stack spilling that needs to happen. But, you have to push new values on the stack in order to create the locals,so the scenarios where it would make an improvement are limited. I would ignore who ever told you that.

Comment: Or maybe it ends up generating exactly the same code, if the jitter is smart enough (and they're damn smart these days).

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers haven't answered the actual question and others are wrong. Accessing a member variable via this.obj requires dereferencing an element on the stack. Accessing a local copy of that reference eliminates the dereference step. So in theory and absent HotSpot the latter has to be more efficient. However unless you are timing nuclear reactions or something the difference will be minimal, and I would deprecate the practice any time I saw it in my shop.